# Several nested DIVs with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, layout

Hello I am trying to vertical and horizontally align 4 divs inside each other with CSS but nothing is working for me.

Please help me! Thanks in advance

[image]

My CSS Please note this is just 1 method ive tried I have been sitting here for about 2 hours messing with this and couldnt figure it out.

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body {
    background-color:#454545;
}

.wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;
}

.circle-wrapper {
    height:918px;
    width:918px;
    background-image:url(images/overlay.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}

.outer-inner-background {
    background-image:url(images/center-circle.GIF);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    height:494px;
    width:494px;
    margin:auto;
}

.outer-inner-rings {
    background-image:url(images/inner-outer-rings.PNG);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    position:relative;
    width:494px;
    height:494px;
    margin:auto;
}

.inner-image {
    position:relative;
    height:308px;
    width:308px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

My HTML: I don't care if the structure changes it just needs to work

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
            <div class="outer-inner-background">
            </div>

            <div class="outer-inner-rings">
            </div>

            <div class="inner-image">
                <img class="inner-img" src="images/inside-image.PNG" width="308px" height="308px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS

Comment: PeeHaa, how would I center that crust to the center then?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rZGb5/3/   that wrapper has a image in it " <div class="circle-wrapper"> "

Answer (score 1):

here my try http://dabblet.com/gist/4013306

code:

css

```
div {overflow:hidden}
#first {
    background:red;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:300px;}
#second {
    background:grey;
    height:95%;
    width:95%;
    border-radius:300px;
    margin:2.5%}
#third {
    background:green;
    height:70%;
    width:70%;
    border-radius:200px;
    margin:15%;}
#forth {
    background:black;
    height:95%;
    width:95%;
    border-radius:200px;
    margin:2.5%;}
```

html

```
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
        <div id="third">
            <div id="forth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: relative;` on the container, and `position: absolute;` on the circles with suitable `left` and `top` values to place them in the middle.

Comment: All can be relative. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Why? If DIVs are nested all can be done with padding/margin. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use absolute positioning in your inner divs where `left` and `top` positions are always set to (`Parent element width` - `child element width` /2). Here's my code

html

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="grey">
        <div id="green">
            <div id="black">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
div
{
    border-radius:100%;
}

#red
{
    position:relative; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto; /** centers #red on screen **/
    background-color: #F00;
    width:400px; 
​    height:400px;

}
#grey
{
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:360px; /** 400 - 360 = 40/2 = 20px for left and top **/
    height:360px;
}

#green
{
    background-color:#0E0;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:40px;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}
#black
{
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    width:240px;
    height:240px;
}​
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/pmN4z/

Fiddle with #red centered on screen:

http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/pmN4z/2/

Comment: How could I center everything in red including red in the center of the screen as well

Comment: hmm but the problem is im using images and when I start to add images bad things happen take a look ( http://jsfiddle.net/HeqyT/1/ )

Comment: So don't use images. You can reproduce what you want without using them, which means it's a lighter solution

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be 4 divs? try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vSyWZ/2/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><div>
</div>
​
```

CSS

```
div{position:relative; margin:0 auto;}
.outer{width: 350px; height: 350px; background-color: gray; border-radius: 100%; border:10px solid red; vertical-align: middle;}
.inner{width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black; border-radius: 100%; border:10px solid green; top:60px;}​
```

I tested on Chrome and Firefox and works fine, IE doesn't have support for rounded corners but it is centered.